# Cannot see Integration Services Catalogs node in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

I wanted to create a SSIS catalog and the way to create a catalog is to right click on "Integration Services Catalogs" node and select "Create Catalog" option.

However, I am not able to see the "Integration Services Catalogs" node in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) as shown in the following image.

What is missing so that I can see this node in SSMS? Please help.

FYI, I have SQL Server 2014 (Developer edition) and Integration Services 12.0 installed on my machine.

[image]

Comment: Which **edition** of SQL Server 2014 do you have? Express, Web, Standard, Developer/Enterprise?

Comment: Do you have any other versions of SQL Server running on your system? or perhaps just another version of SSMS? You can't see the Integration Services Catalogs in SSMS 2008 or older.

Comment: No I have only 1 version of SSMS, and thats 2014.

Comment: On that server, run this query `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS ProductVersion;` What does that say?

Comment: ProductVersion = 12.0.2269.0

Comment: Can you try creating the catalog programmatically, using PowerShell, as mentioned here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471509.aspx

Comment: I ran the powershell script and after fixing some permission issues with powershell, the script executed without an error. The script output said "connecting to server..." after listing GAC assembly. So, I guess it connected to server and created the database. However, I don't see the Integration Services Catalogs node, although I restarted services for SQL Server and Integration Services.

Comment: Are you an administrator on that SQL Server instance? If you right-click on the SSMS icon and choose Run as Administrator, does that resolve the issue?

Comment: No, that didn't help too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got resolved for me!

FYI, I had to launch SQL Server Setup again and install the named instance (\) of SQL Server. So, when I connect to Named Instance of SQL Server I am able to see the "Integration Services Catalogs" node on Object Explorer (see below).

[image]

However, although it is resolved for me and I am able to move forward for now, I am not sure why its not able to show me this node when I connect to SQL Server default instance.

[MS Technet Reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7e015468-64d1-40f9-8f58-42fa1efc12ff/cannot-see-integration-services-catalogs-node-in-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?forum=sqlintegrationservices)