# Missing Integration Services Catalog in SSMS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2014

I have SQL Server 2014 installed. The option of the integration services catalog is missing under the database connection.

I have the role sysadmin when I log in SQL Server

Any ideas? Help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot see Integration Services Catalogs node in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853280/cannot-see-integration-services-catalogs-node-in-sql-server-management-studio-s)

Answer (score 2):

Please look at this question and see if it solves your issue.

[Cannot see Integration Services Catalogs node in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853280/cannot-see-integration-services-catalogs-node-in-sql-server-management-studio-s)

The person had to launch SQL Server Setup again and install the named instance '\' of SQL Server

Comment: You are welcome, also if the answer is correct and it is the solution you used then you should mark it as accepted

Comment: @hadi it's the checkmark beneath the number beneath the arrow lol